# Installing packages on python 2.7 on windows 95

Tags: python-2.7, pip, windows-95

I have found a version of python 2.7.3 for windows 9x here.
http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/162317-python-27-for-windows-95/

And downloaded it for use on my windows 95 laptop. I realise this is unusual so its not surprising to run into problems, however it didn't come wit pip, so I can't install any new packages. I have tried running get-pip.py but this fails after some progress due to "AttributeError: function 'SHGetFolderPathW' not found, when get-pip.pt is trying to use **init**.py from ctypes. SHGetFolderPathW is something supported by shell32.dll in windows 2000 onwards, the equivalent is SHGetFileInfo from the shfolder.dll I believe.

I can't figure out how to replace the parts of the code that tries to call SHGetFolderpathW and replace it so that pip will install (or at least get further).

I hope someone can help, though I realise this is an extremely EXTREMELY niche problem.

Comment: Contact python: bottom of page is their &m@ail: https://www.python.org/about/help/

Comment: Thanks for replying :)